# Stored Procedure Performance : DataNotFound or External Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

Below is the small snippet of my Stored Procedure.I am using Oracle database.
I feel that below is not the good way. Firstly I am checking through count that weather I am getting a row from a query. Then if count ( CNT2 > 0 ) is greater than 0 means I got the record from query then I am again executing query to get the columns.

This is sort of repetition of query. Like firstly I am checking through count and then executing query again if count is greater than 0.

I have 10 queries in my procedure and for each query i am checking count first then again executing query if count is greater than 0. I believe that this is not good for performance point of view.

I checked on net and found that we can catch it through DATANOTFOUND exception and can use external cursor. I am new in this and not sure how to do this. Which one is better option for performance point of view.

```
.............
.............
BEGIN
      oAuditMsg := 'audit : ';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Debug :: inside begin' );

      select count(*) into CNT2  from COMMON_MAPPING where IP like VAR_IP ; 

       IF CNT2 >0 THEN
         select Out_IP,Out_IP1 into VAR_OUTIP, VAR_OUTIP1 from from COMMON_MAPPING where IP like VAR_IP ; 

       ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Record found in table COMMON_MAPPING');

       END IF;

..............
..............
..............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 possibilities.

Your method with count is not safe (my option 2).
If another session deletes the row that met the condition after the line with the count and before the line with the select .. into - the code will throw an exception that is not handled...

The option 1 is preferred. However the performance can be a little lower due to handling of exception. But it's not significant comparing to problem that you can have with not handled exception.
You mentioned about option 3 - there is an example how to use it.

**Option 1:**

```
select Out_IP,Out_IP1 INTO VAR_OUTIP, VAR_OUTIP1 from COMMON_MAPPING where IP like VAR_IP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
...
```

**Option 2:**

```
 select count(*) into CNT2  from COMMON_MAPPING where IP like VAR_IP ; 

       IF CNT2 >0 THEN
         select Out_IP,Out_IP1 into VAR_OUTIP, VAR_OUTIP1 from from COMMON_MAPPING where IP like VAR_IP ;
```

**Option 3:**

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR foo_rec IN ( select Out_IP,Out_IP1 from COMMON_MAPPING where IP like VAR_IP)
 LOOP
     ...
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE;
END ;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I checked on net and found that we can catch it through DATANOTFOUND exception

You need to use **NO_DATA_FOUND** exception.

For example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_ename VARCHAR2(20);
  3    v_empno NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5    v_empno := 9999;
  6    SELECT ename INTO v_ename FROM emp WHERE empno = v_empno;
  7    IF v_ename IS NOT NULL THEN
  8      dbms_output.put_line('Employee found');
  9      -- do something
 10    END IF;
 11  EXCEPTION
 12  WHEN no_data_found THEN
 13    dbms_output.put_line('Inside Exception because Employee not found');
 14    -- do something
 15  WHEN OTHERS THEN
 16    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Unexpected error');
 17    RAISE;
 18  END;
 19  /
Inside Exception because Employee not found

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Usually you don't use **DBMS_OUTPUT** in production code, use the exception block for logging the errors into an error logging table. It should be robust an helpful for the developers to understand the error easily for debugging purpose.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS00702),

> Advantages of Exception Handlers
>
> Using exception handlers for error-handling makes programs easier to
>   write and understand, and reduces the likelihood of unhandled
>   exceptions.
>
> Without exception handlers, you must check for every possible error,
>   everywhere that it might occur, and then handle it. It is easy to
>   overlook a possible error or a place where it might occur, especially
>   if the error is not immediately detectable (for example, bad data
>   might be undetectable until you use it in a calculation).
>   Error-handling code is scattered throughout the program.
>
> With exception handlers, you need not know every possible error or
>   everywhere that it might occur. You need only include an
>   exception-handling part in each block where errors might occur. In the
>   exception-handling part, you can include exception handlers for both
>   specific and unknown errors. If an error occurs anywhere in the block
>   (including inside a sub-block), then an exception handler handles it.
>   Error-handling code is isolated in the exception-handling parts of the
>   blocks.

**Regarding your question on performance:**

> and can use external cursor.

I think you mean an **explicit cursor**. From performance point of view, it is not a good idea. I would prefer a combination of **CURSOR FOR LOOP** and  **FOR ALL** statement along with **BULK COLLECT**.

In the recent Oracle versions, **CURSOR FOR LOOP** is optimized in a better way by doing a `bulk collect limit 100` **internally**.

But, it's not just about bulk collecting, we are dealing with the operations we would subsequently do on the array that we have fetched incrementally. We could further improve the performance by using FORALL statement along with BULK COLLECT.

Having said that, it would be much faster if you could do it in **pure SQL**. SQL and PL/SQL are different, and needs a context switch between the two engines when you do a **SQL call in PL/SQL**, or vice-versa, i.e. a **PL/SQL call in SQL**. With every context switch between the two engines, there is a performance overhead. The "hit" is most evident when SQL invokes PLSQL - not so much the other way, when SQL is embedded in PLSQL.

Comment: Which one is better considering performance. Exception handling or using cursor. Option 1 or Option 3 if you see above answer, I was planning to use Option 3. Your recommendation ?

Comment: @VJS Depends on what your business logic is. In your code I only see a `SELECT ..INTO` statement which doesn't have any performance issues. Your question is mostly on how to catch `no_data_found` exception. you said you have 10 queries, what do they do? Are they all same but just fetching different rows from same table?

Comment: Are the queries are not that complex just fetching different columns from different tablles

Comment: @VJS Then you should not worry about performance. But, why do you want to do it in **PL/SQL**, why not execute the queries in pure **SQL**?. SQL is always faster than PL/SQL.

Comment: May be this is just the stub what @VJS has given. If this has to be passed to the Front end application like JAVA or anything else he has to use Procedure of function. Inthis case suggestion will be using Cursor.

Answer (score 0):

As per the problem statement provided. I can suggest two approaches below.
    First option would be using Ref Cursor as you need not to worry about this kind of exception handling. -- My Favourite
    Second approach would be as suggested above catching the exception in the Exception block. I have included another OTHERS clause in exception handling as it can happen there can be others errors to that may come like TOO_MANY_ROWS.

```
-- Option 1  --> Using Ref Cursor
DECLARE
  CNT2 PLS_INTEGER:=0;
  oAuditMsg  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
  VAR_OUTIP  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);-- Assuming this field is VARCHAR
  VAR_OUTIP1 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);-- Assuming this field is VARCHAR
  VAR_IP     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
  p_lst sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  oAuditMsg:= 'audit : ';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Debug :: inside begin' );
  OPEN p_lst FOR SELECT Out_IP, Out_IP1 FROM COMMON_MAPPING WHERE IP LIKE VAR_IP ;
END;

-- Option 2  --> Using NoDataFound Exception Clause

DECLARE
--  CNT2 PLS_INTEGER:=0; -- Not required
  oAuditMsg  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
  VAR_OUTIP  VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);-- Assuming this field is VARCHAR
  VAR_OUTIP1 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);-- Assuming this field is VARCHAR
  VAR_IP     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
--  p_lst sys_refcursor; -- Not required
BEGIN
  oAuditMsg:= 'audit : ';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Debug :: inside begin' );
  BEGIN
  SELECT Out_IP, Out_IP1 
  INTO 
  VAR_OUTIP,
  VAR_OUTIP1
  FROM COMMON_MAPPING WHERE IP LIKE VAR_IP ;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,SQLERRM,TRUE);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,SQLERRM,TRUE);
  END;
END;
```

Let me know if this helps.